# How to compile a document with the pstool package using the pdflatexmk script?

Tags: errors, pdftex, latexmk, psfrag

To use `psfrag` with pdflatex I use the `pstool` package. Using TeXShop 3.25 I can compile the two minimal working examples given in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139335/13134) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96165/13134) answer when I use the regular LaTeX typesetter.

The MWE from the [first answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139335/13134) looks as follows:

```
% compiled by `pdflatex --shell-escape` enabled
\documentclass{book}
\listfiles % to show the list of packages loaded in .log file
\usepackage[crop=pdfcrop,process=all,cleanup={.tex,.dvi,.ps,.pdf,.log}]{pstool} 
% Good options for pstool package
\EndPreamble % Will help to pick the right preamble in pstool auxillary process 
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{trial.eps}
\caption{Tagged eps image}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\psfragfig[width=0.8\linewidth]{trial}{\color{red}
  \psfrag{[Mp]}{$M_A$}%
  \psfrag{[hb]}{$H_B$}} 
\caption{Replacing tags with real labels with psfrag}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And the MWE from the [second answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96165/13134) is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pstool}
\def\a{A}
\EndPreamble
\begin{document}

\psfragfig*[mode=nonstop]{trial}{%
  \color{red}
  \tiny
  \psfrag{[Mp]}{$M_\a$!}%
}

\end{document}
```

When I use the `pdflatexmk` script - which I have modified according to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139177/13134) to include the shell escape option required by `pstool` - the compilation of both the aforementioned examples always ends in this error message:

```
Latexmk: Maximum runs of pdflatex reached without getting stable files
Latexmk: Did not finish processing file 'trialctan2.tex':
   'pdflatex' needed too many passes
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs of latex/pdflatex.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Latexmk: All targets (trialctan2.pdf) are up-to-date
```

Why is this error happening and how can I get rid of it?
I tried adding the `-f` option to the `pdflatexmk` script as follows:

```
"${LTMKBIN}"/latexmk -pdf -r "${LTMKEDIT}/latexmkrcedit" -r "${TSBIN}/pdflatexmkrc" -f -pdflatex="pdflatex --shell-escape %O %S" "$1"
```

But the same error persists.

**Update 1:**

Digging around I found that the culprit is the `process=all` option. In the second MWE it is locally enabled by the asterisk after `psfragfig`.
With this option the pdf file for each eps figure is recreated on every run. I suspect that the `pdflatexmk` script notices this and decides it needs to run again as something has changed, triggering a new eps to pdf conversion, noticing it again, etc...
I think I need to find out how to restrict the `process=all` option to the first run only.

Comment: Concerning the last part of your question, you did not add the `-f` flag to the `latexmk` program; you added it to the `pdflatex` program, which does not recognize it.  You should put it right before the `-pdflatex=` flag if you want it.

Comment: Concerning the first (and main) part of your question, I cannot help much without a working example.

Comment: I have placed the `-f` flag correctly now, but the error remains. As for the MWE's, the links in the first paragraph to two answers contain the MWE's that I try to compile. I have now added them in my question explicitly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the file `trial.pdf` is created on every run, and it is always different from the previous version.  Since `latexmk` notices the change, it presumes that `pdflatex` has to be run again.  Near the end of its output is the reason:

```
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
  'trial.pdf'
```

This is just above the output that is quoted in the question.

Possible solutions:

1. The changes are irrelevant to the final output, so you have to tell `latexmk` to ignore them.  This can be done by adding the following line to an appropriate `latexmkrc` file:

   ```
   $hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'pdf'} = '^/CreationDate |^/ModDate |^/ID \\[<';
   ```

   However, there remains the problem that with the posted MWE the `.pdf` file is recreated on every run of `pdflatex`, whether or not it is needed, which can be excessively time consuming.
2. Alternatively, you can stop `pstool` from recreating `trial.pdf` on every run by replacing `process=all` by `process=auto` in the options list for `pstool` in the first example.  In the second example you remove the `*` after `\psfragfig`. But this won't update the pdf file if the `psfrag` substitutions are changed; the only updates are when the `.eps` file changes.
3. Another solution is to delegate the making of the `.pdf` file to `latexmk`.  For this you should turn off the use of the `-shell-escape` option to `pdflatex`. To make this work needs a bit of trickery in a `latexmkrc` file.  Here is appropriate code to put into one of the `latexmkrc` files:

   ```
   $pdf_mode = 1;
   $dvi_mode = $postscript_mode = 0;
   # Don't use the following files for a default make
   # by latexmk (i.e., with no files on the command line):
   @default_excluded_files = ( '*-pstool.tex' );
   add_cus_dep( 'eps', 'pdf', 0, eps2pdf_pstool );
   $pdflatex = 'internal pdflatex_pstool %O %S';
   # Patterns to ignore in detecting changes in pdf files made by pstool
   $hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'pdf'} = '^/CreationDate |^/ModDate |^/ID \\[<';

   sub pdflatex_pstool {
      # This subroutine runs pdflatex with some pre- and post-processing
      #    that is appropriate when the  pstool package is used.
      #
      # Ensure that there is a dummy pstool-statusfile.txt file so that 
      #   during the run of pdflatex, the pstool package isn't unhappy
      #   enough to report an error.
      if ( ! -e "pstool-statusfile.txt" ) {
         system( "echo 1 > pstool-statusfile.txt" );
      }
      # The actual run of pdflatex, with the specified arguments this
      #   subroutine has  been given
      my $return = system( 'pdflatex', @_ );
      # Fix up the dependencies on eps files given special processing by
      #    pstool.  These are flagged by the existence of files named
      #    "*-pstool.tex".  To get latexmk to use these, it is sufficient
      #    to tell it that there is a corresponding pdf file that needs
      #    to be made. 
      foreach my $cand ( glob "*-pstool.tex" ) {
         # Get the basename of the associated graphics file.
         # This is done by Perl regex on the r.h.s. of the assignment in
         #    the next statement.  The variable $base is surrounded by
         #    parentheses, so that ($base) is a one-element array to
         #    which is assigned the first pattern ($1) in parentheses in
         #    the regex. Without the parentheses around $base, $base
         #    would be set to an essentially boolean value for a
         #    successful search.
         my ($base) = ($cand =~ /^(.*)-pstool.tex$/ );
         if ( -e "$base.eps" ) {
            # We get here if we know that both a $base-pstool.tex file
            #   and a $base.eps file exists.  This indicates that there
            #   is a file $base.pdf that needs to be made from $base.eps
            #   with the aid of applying latex to $base-pstool.tex.
            # The important thing is that this pdf file is a source file
            #   of the main run of pdflatex (and hence for the rule used
            #   to invoke the current subroutine).
            # Once the dependency on the pdf file is set, latexmk
            #   will do the rest, by finding the eps file from which the
            #   pdf file is made and setting a suitable rule to make the
            #   pdf file, by the custom dependency method.
            rdb_ensure_file( $rule, "$base.pdf" );
         }
      }
      return $return;
   }

   sub eps2pdf_pstool {
      # Note that when this subroutine is invoked, $rule is set to the
      #   name of the current rule (which is an eps to pdf custom
      #   dependency). 
      my $base = $_[0];
      my $source = "$base.eps";
      my $dest = "$base.pdf";
      my $pstool_base = "$base-pstool";
      if ( -e "$pstool_base.tex" ) {
         # Use pstool processing chain
         #
         # This rule needs a dependency on the tex file used to make
         #    the pdf file:
         rdb_ensure_file( $rule, "$pstool_base.tex" );
         my $return = 0;
         # Generate the pdf file by the method used by pstool
         # I assume that the image is to be cropped.
         # The following code copies what pstool would do directly from
         #   the main run of pdflatex if it were allowed by a option
         #   shell-escape to pdflatex.
         $return = 
            system( "latex",
                    "-output-format=dvi",
                    "-interaction=batchmode",
                    "-shell-escape",
                    "$pstool_base.tex" )
            || system( "dvips", "-q", "-Ppdf", "$pstool_base.dvi" )
            || system( "ps2pdf",
                       "-dAutoFilterColorImages=false",
                       "-dAutoFilterGrayImages=false",
                       "-dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode",
                       "-dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode",
                       "-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress",
                       "$pstool_base.ps",
                       "$pstool_base.pdf" )
            || system( "pdfcrop", "$pstool_base.pdf", "$base.pdf" );
         # The pstool package likes the result of the commands to be
         #    stored in a status file:
         system( "echo $return > pstool-statusfile.txt" );
         if ( $return == 0 ) {
            # If there was no error, clean up intermediate files, but
            #   leave them as they if there was an error; the user may
            #   want to  use the files to diagnose the error.  
            # But leave the aux file, since pstool wants to read it.
            foreach my $ext ( "log", "dvi", "ps", "pdf" ) {
               unlink "$pstool_base.$ext";
            }
         }
         return $return;
      }
      else {
         # Use standard epstopdf processing
         return system( "epstopdf $_[0].eps --outfile=$_[0].pdf" );
      }
   }
   ```

   Note: When using this solution, it is a good idea to invoke the `pstool` package in the main `latex` document by

   ```
   \usepackage[crop=pdfcrop,process=auto,cleanup={.dvi,.ps,.pdf,.log}]{pstool}
   ```

   This will ensure that if you do happen to invoke `pdflatex` with the `-shell-escape` option, it won't interfere too much with the work that `latexmk` does.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. No.1 seems like the option I'm looking for as no.2 doesn't fit my needs. When I change the scale of the image, or the replacement text, the image also needs to update, not only when the eps has changed. Could you please elaborate on where I should place the code line in the `pdflatexmk` script?

Comment: A suitable place to put the line is in a file named `latexmkrc` in the same directory as the `latex` file.  That's a configuration file read by `latexmk` when it starts up.  (See the `latexmk` documentation for more details on how it is configured.)